# Differentiability Vs. Continuity

Tags: calculus

Let $$f(x)=\frac{x^2+x-6}{x^2+5x+6}$$ Is $f$ continuous at the point $x=-3$? Is $f$ differentiable at point $x=-3$? Is it really possible that a function is differentiable on a point (not in domain) but not continuous on that point?

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity. The contrapositive is also true: discontinuity implies non-differentiability. What can you say about $f(-3)$? Does it exist?

Comment: $f(x)=\frac {x-2} {x+2}$. If you define the value of $f$ at $-3$ to be $5$ then it is differentiable (and hence continuous). As it is, it is neither continuous nor differentiable

Comment: The left and right hand limits are both 5 @shubham johri

Comment: Im confuse about continuity because -3 is not part of its domain. So its means that f is continuous everywhere except -3 and -2.

Answer (score 2):

A function cannot be continuous and it can't be differentiable at a point where it isn't defined. Your function $f$ is only defined on $\Bbb R\setminus \{-3, -2\}$, and thus asking whether it's continuous at $x = -3$ is meaningless. Note that the function isn't *discontinuous* either. Asking whether it's discontinuous at $x = -3$ is equally meaningless.

That being said, for all *other* values of $x$, we have that $f(x)$ is equal to $\frac{x-2}{x+2}$, and that function *is* defined and continuous at $x = -3$. Thus we way that $f$ has a *removable singularity* at $x = -3$. If we remove this singularity, then yes, the new function is both continuous and differentiable at $x = -3$.

Comment: I am still confused especially with the removable singularity. :|

Comment: @perfectnumber You can remove the singularity, but that would result in a _new, different_ function. The original function isn't defined at $x = -3$, and thus it can't be continuous there. It doesn't matter what kind of "undefinability" it has. Removable or not, the function simply isn't defined, and that's the end of it.

Comment: In other words, f is not continuous at x=-3 hence not differentiable?

Comment: @perfectnumber Exactly. I think i would personally use "and" instead of "hence" in this specific case. As I see it, the function not being defined stops both properties, rather than it stopping continuity, which in turn stops differentiability. But that's a matter of philosophy and esthetics, and what you said is entirely correct.

Comment: One clarification @Arthur, it doesn't mean that the derivative of f is defined at x=-3, f is also differentiable at x=-3?

Comment: @perfectnumber No, $f$ is not differentiable at $x = -3$. The derivative isn't defined at $x = -3$. If you calculate the derivative, and you get an expression which happens to make sense at $x = -3$, that doesn't change anything.